# Разбить обновление бд на пакеты (Пакетная загрузка)

Tags: php, mysql, xml

Сайт на PHP+MYSQL.
Сторонний сайт предоставляет XML выгрузку. Обрабатываю готовую выгрузку по опр. условиям и передаю на свой сайт в бд. Нужно реализовать пакетную реализацию для снижения нагрузки и времени записи данных.
Парсинг идет через xpath. В foreach есть SELECT, условий с continue и 1 INSERT. Как разбить на пакеты - ума не приложу.

```
foreach ($xmlTree->xpath('/doct//page/product') as $tree) 
{
    $prid = (array) $tree->product;
    $prid = $prid[0];

    $pgid = (array) $tree->page;
    $pgid = $pgid[0];

    //Проверяем, есть ли товар с таким id
    $ge = db::getInstance()->db()->query('SELECT id FROM goods_from_site WHERE product_id=?d', $prid);
    if(!empty($ge)){
        continue;
    }

    db::getInstance()->db()->query('INSERT INTO `goods_from_site` (`product_id`, `rid2`) 
        VALUES ("'.$prid.'","'.$pgid.'")');
}
```

Comment: для начала надо посмотреть что за несколько select, действительно ли они нужны. пока есть select на каждую строку про пакетную обработку можно забыть. И кстати, главное в этом деле подготовленные (один раз перед циклом) запросы, что бы внутри цикла были только execute (и возможно bind)

Comment: Проверяю есть ли товар с таким айдишником, если нет - то добавляю. Если есть, то перехожу к другому.

`foreach ($xmlTree->xpath('/doct//page/product') as $tree) 
{
 $prid = (array) $tree->product;
 $prid = $prid[0];

 $pgid = (array) $tree->page;
 $pgid = $pgid[0];

 //Проверяем, есть ли товар с таким id
 $ge = db::getInstance()->db()->query('SELECT id FROM goods_from_site WHERE product_id=?d', $prid);
 if(!empty($ge)){
  continue;
 }

 db::getInstance()->db()->query('INSERT INTO `goods_from_site` (`product_id`, `rid2`) 
  VALUES ("'.$prid.'","'.$pgid.'")');
}

Comment: Если по колонке product_id есть уникальный индекс (или она первичный ключ, или ограничение unique) то вы можете использовать `insert IGNORE into ...` и проверка вам уже не нужна, он вставит только новые строки. плюс к этому надо переходить на подготовленные выражения. перед циклом делаете `$q=prepare('insert .... values(?,?)`, а в цикле выполняете `$q->execute( array($prid,$pgid );` (для PDO, в случае mysqli придется еще делать bind внутри цикла). до 50% времени работы вставки в БД занимает компиляция нового запроса из текста

Comment: А других вариантов кроме PDO нет?

Comment: аналогично mysqli только там в execute параметры передавать нельзя, приходится bind делать, но на скорость это не должно влиять, просто чуть сложнее код